# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, oracle11g

When `saveDepartment()` is invoked, I am getting exception mentioned in the title. After searching for solution for a while I came up with another similar post on stackoverflow which doesn't match the problem scenario I am facing.

---

Dao class:

```
@Repository
public class DepartmentDaoImpl implements DepartmentDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveDepartment(Department department) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(department);
    }
}
```

---

Bean configuration section for hibernate:

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.therap.domain.tmp"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Any suggestion or solution regarding the problem is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using oracle? if so, why you've added HSQL dialect? add more details(stacktrace, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORA-06576` error code and `oracle11g` tag are suggesting you're using Oracle 11g Database.

Hibernate's `Oracle10gDialect` is compatible with that version, so you should use following dialect configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.therap.domain.tmp"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I was switching from mysql to oracle, that is the very important thing i shouldn't have missed. Thank you mkierc for the fast and to the point response